# App is not deployed after "git push dokku master"

Tags: dokku

I'm trying to deploy an app with Dokku on Digital Ocean. I made some changes locally and push to GitHub succesfully. I see changes on GitHub. After that, I'm trying deploy app with "git push dokku master" and everything goes successfully but, app doesn't change. What could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you contact Digital Ocean ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you pushing to the right remote app? Sometimes, Dokku users will push to a git remote like:

```
# where dokku.me is your hostname
dokku@dokku.me:www.lollipop.com
```

If your app is called `lollipop`, then the remote should be `dokku@dokku.me:lollipop`, without the domain.

Similarly, some users set the remote to `dokku@dokku.me:lollipop.git`, which is *also* not the app name, so again, the app looks deployed, but its actually a different app that is deployed.

Check the remote and verify that the output of `dokku apps:list` on the server matches what you expect, and change your remote if necessary.